# Swift ESTabBarController large center button fail

Tags: ios, swift, uitabbarcontroller, uitabbar

I download and run [ESTabBarController](https://github.com/eggswift/ESTabBarController) fine but I don't know why when I create my own project and use code from Example, my large button still small??

[image]

While image below is from example project as my expectation as well
[image]
Here is my code

**AppDelegate.swift**

```
let TabbarNavigationController = ViewController.customIrregularityStyle(delegate: nil)
self.window?.rootViewController = TabbarNavigationController
```

**ViewController.swift**

```
static func customIrregularityStyle(delegate: UITabBarControllerDelegate?) -> NavigationController {
    let tabBarController = ESTabBarController()
    tabBarController.delegate = delegate
    tabBarController.title = "Irregularity"
    tabBarController.tabBar.shadowImage = UIImage(named: "transparent")
    tabBarController.tabBar.backgroundImage = UIImage(named: "background_dark")
    tabBarController.shouldHijackHandler = {
        tabbarController, viewController, index in
        if index == 2 {
            return true
        }
        return false
    }
    tabBarController.didHijackHandler = {
        [weak tabBarController] tabbarController, viewController, index in

        DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 0.2) {
            let alertController = UIAlertController.init(title: nil, message: nil, preferredStyle: .actionSheet)
            let takePhotoAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Take a photo", style: .default, handler: nil)
            alertController.addAction(takePhotoAction)
            let selectFromAlbumAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Select from album", style: .default, handler: nil)
            alertController.addAction(selectFromAlbumAction)
            let cancelAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .cancel, handler: nil)
            alertController.addAction(cancelAction)
            tabBarController?.present(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
        }
    }

    let v1 = ExampleViewController()
    let v2 = ExampleViewController()
    let v3 = ExampleViewController()
    let v4 = ExampleViewController()
    let v5 = ExampleViewController()

    v1.tabBarItem = ESTabBarItem.init(IrregularityBasicContentView(), title: "Home", image: UIImage(named: "home"), selectedImage: UIImage(named: "home_1"))
    v2.tabBarItem = ESTabBarItem.init(IrregularityBasicContentView(), title: "Find", image: UIImage(named: "find"), selectedImage: UIImage(named: "find_1"))
    v3.tabBarItem = ESTabBarItem.init(IrregularityBasicContentView(), title: nil, image: UIImage(named: "photo_verybig"), selectedImage: UIImage(named: "photo_verybig"))
    v4.tabBarItem = ESTabBarItem.init(IrregularityBasicContentView(), title: "Favor", image: UIImage(named: "favor"), selectedImage: UIImage(named: "favor_1"))
    v5.tabBarItem = ESTabBarItem.init(IrregularityBasicContentView(), title: "Me", image: UIImage(named: "me"), selectedImage: UIImage(named: "me_1"))

    tabBarController.viewControllers = [v1, v2, v3, v4, v5]

    let navigationController = NavigationController.init(rootViewController: tabBarController)
    tabBarController.title = "Example"
    return navigationController
}
```

Any idea?

Comment: if you are talking about why the middle image is too small then its issue with the image size, if you are using ESTabBarController's asset try to change this line v3.tabBarItem = ESTabBarItem.init(IrregularityBasicContentView(), title: nil, image: UIImage(named: "photo_big"), selectedImage: UIImage(named: "photo_big"))

Comment: @SaifanNadaf I have already changed that but no help, you can see my expectation result at this image https://i.imgur.com/0i30rDPl.png

Comment: Added Answer pls check and let me know if any issue

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to use custom tabBar and add your button in centre of tabBar [Like This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30527738/how-do-we-create-a-bigger-center-uitabbar-item)

If you want to use ESTabBarController follow the below steps.

**Step 1:** 
Download the sample project of [ESTabBarController](https://github.com/eggswift/ESTabBarController) and install `pod "ESTabBarController-swift"` in your project

**Step 2:**
Copy all the assets from sample project into your existing project

**Step 3:**
Copy `ExampleBasicContentView`, `ExampleBouncesContentView` , `ExampleIrregularityContentView`, `ExampleNavigationController` Classes from sample project

> NOTE -  If you got error “No such module 'pop'” in
>   “`ExampleIrregularityBasicContentView`” Then remove that line and
>   remove `func playMaskAnimation` Or install pod  pop

**Step 4:**
In StoryBoard Embbed your `viewController` in navigationController and assign `ExampleNavigationController` class to your navigationController

**Step 5:**
import `ESTabBarController_swift` and add `UITabBarControllerDelegate` in your `AppDelegate` class
Add paste following code in your `AppDelegate` class

```
  func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {


        let tabBarController = ESTabBarController()
        tabBarController.delegate = self
        tabBarController.tabBar.shadowImage = UIImage(named: "transparent")
        tabBarController.tabBar.backgroundImage = UIImage(named: "background_dark")

        tabBarController.shouldHijackHandler = {
            tabbarController, viewController, index in
            if index == 2 {
                return true
            }
            return false
        }

        tabBarController.didHijackHandler = {
            [weak tabBarController] tabbarController, viewController, index in

            DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 0.2) {
                let alertController = UIAlertController.init(title: nil, message: nil, preferredStyle: .actionSheet)
                let takePhotoAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Take a photo", style: .default, handler: nil)
                alertController.addAction(takePhotoAction)
                let selectFromAlbumAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Select from album", style: .default, handler: nil)
                alertController.addAction(selectFromAlbumAction)
                let cancelAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .cancel, handler: nil)
                alertController.addAction(cancelAction)
                tabBarController?.present(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
            }
        }

        let v1 = ViewController()
        let v2 = ViewController()
        let v3 = ViewController()
        let v4 = ViewController()
        let v5 = ViewController()

        v1.tabBarItem = ESTabBarItem.init(ExampleIrregularityBasicContentView(), title: "Home", image: UIImage(named: "home"), selectedImage: UIImage(named: "home_1"))
        v2.tabBarItem = ESTabBarItem.init(ExampleIrregularityBasicContentView(), title: "Find", image: UIImage(named: "find"), selectedImage: UIImage(named: "find_1"))
        v3.tabBarItem = ESTabBarItem.init(ExampleIrregularityContentView(), title: nil, image: UIImage(named: "photo_verybig"), selectedImage: UIImage(named: "photo_verybig"))
        v4.tabBarItem = ESTabBarItem.init(ExampleIrregularityBasicContentView(), title: "Favor", image: UIImage(named: "favor"), selectedImage: UIImage(named: "favor_1"))
        v5.tabBarItem = ESTabBarItem.init(ExampleIrregularityBasicContentView(), title: "Me", image: UIImage(named: "me"), selectedImage: UIImage(named: "me_1"))

        tabBarController.viewControllers = [v1, v2, v3, v4, v5]

        let navigationController = ExampleNavigationController.init(rootViewController: tabBarController)
        self.window?.rootViewController = navigationController

         return true
    }
```

You can find demo [here](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1jFdrbNP7d7MB37rNLkXo_3PNFOEEOJYT)

**ScreenShot :**

[image]

Comment: It works, actually I'm confused at `ExampleIrregularityBasicContentView` and `ExampleIrregularityContentView` while the second one is for big button